# Strategies for dealing with disasters

Tags: banished

How can I setup my village to optimize its resiliency against disasters? So far, I've experienced a fire and a tornado.

After the fire destroyed my village, I decided to make house clusters a little distance from one another, so the fire won't spread so easily. But I don't know what's the minimum safe distance that won't allow a fire to spread to the nearest building.

Then a tornado ripped through my city, destroying all my storage barns and condemning all citizens to death by starvation. I have no idea how to deal with tornadoes.

Comment: Disasters are disasters for a reason. If you could plan for them they wouldn't be so disastrous.

Answer (score 3):

Diversification. Don't keep all buildings of a certain type together. Disasters destroy buildings in a small area. If all your food producing buildings or storage buildings are in the same area, they are susceptible to the same disaster. If you stagger them instead you will lose a variety of buildings, which is more manageable than all buildings of a given type.

Comment: I try to spread out quickly, building redundant micro-towns or small specialized micro-towns all over the map.  I asked a question related to this which might help (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156822/what-buildings-are-recommended-for-an-offshoot-settlement)

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing 3 fires in 1-2 years and losing about half of my food supply (losing 1 market and 2 Storage Barns) I started building Markets with 4 road blocks around. This seems to isolates them from fire. I also build space in between houses to not have to many of them start burning when the fire comes.